# can I assign variable names as shown below in php?

Tags: php

```
$iname=$_POST[${'ingname'.$i}];
```

I have a problem where i need to get values from a form which has dynamically created names with names ending as ingname1,ingname2 and so on.am trying by assigning variable name as shown above but it doesn't work.please suggest any working solution.there is a question asking just the concatenation part but not inside POST method.

Comment: Read this may help https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222248/loop-through-multiple-post-variables-using-dynamic-naming.It may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply remove the curly brace

```
$iname = $_POST['ingname'.$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that the curly braces are unnecessary and the code can be rewritten as `$iname=$_POST['ingname'.$i}];`

The `.` operator is a concatenation operator for php. When you use braces or quotes it is interpreted otherwise.
Edit : `$iname=$_POST['ingname'.$i];`